# Definition of Representation in terms of Group Action

Tags: representation-theory, group-actions

The definition of a representation of a group $G$ over a vector space $V$ is a map $p: G \to GL(V)$.  According to wikipedia, for finite groups an equivalent definition is an action of $G$ on $V$.  I'm having trouble seeing how these two definitions are equivalent.

An action of $G$ on $V$ means a map $G \times V \to V$ satisfying $(gh)v=g(hv)$ and $ev=v$.  I see how a map $G \times V \to V$ determines a function from $G$ to the set of functions on $V$ - just fix a $g$ and the function $f_g$ is defined by $f_g(v)=gv$.  Further, I see how the axioms for a group action mean that this function from $G$ to the set of functions on $V$ is a map: the compatibility axiom guarenteed that $f_h \circ f_g=f_{gh}$.  However, I am struggling to see why the function $f_g$ from $V$ to $V$ is necessarily a linear transformation.  How do we get from the set of functions on $V$ to the set of linear transformations on $V$?

Comment: What Ehsan said - this is typically part of the definition of a representation as a group action.

Comment: A group action on a vector space does ***not*** need to be linear. In order to define a representation as a group action, you must *specify* that it is a linear action.

Comment: anon - the quote I read from wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_finite_groups) is: "A representation ρ: G → GL(n,C) defines a group action of G on the vector space Cn".  You're saying this is not using the normal definition of a group acting on a set - there's an added condition that g(av+w)=a(gv)+gw?

Comment: @goatman2743 A barebones group action on $V$ would be $G\to{\rm Perm}(V)$ where $V$ is the vector space. The group of autobijections/permutations ${\rm Perm}(V)$ of the underlying set of $V$ is *much bigger* than ${\rm GL}(V)$, which is by definition the group of *linear transformations* of $V$ (it is called the "general linear group" if you want to look it up). For instance, a two-dimensional real representation would look like $G\to{\rm GL}_2(\Bbb R)$, but the so-called *affine group* ${\rm Aff}(\Bbb R^2)$ acts on $\Bbb R^2$ by some maps that are not additive (e.g. translations).

Comment: The Wikipedia quote is correct, and is using the normal definition of a group action. A representation is a special case of a group action, so WP is right to say a representation defines a group action. Your claim "according to Wikipedia, for finite groups an equivalent definition is an action of $G$ on $V$" is wrong though: just because a representation defines ("defines" here being interchangeable with "induces" or "is") a group action does *not* mean that just *any* group action defines a representation; it must be linear.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

What seems to have been confusing the asker (or lacking from the source they used) is the distinction between [a permutation representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_representation) and [a (linear) representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_representation) of a group.

In the former case the group $G$ acts on a set $X$ that may not (or may?) have some additional structure. Often the set $X$ is finite, when the action gives rise to a homomorphism of groups $\phi:G\to Sym(X)\cong S_n, n=|X|$. This allows us to use a permutation $\phi(g)$ to do calculations involving the group element $g$. Tools from combinatorics then come to the fore, and can be used to study the group $G$.

In the latter case we study homomorphisms $\phi:G\to GL(V)$, $V$ a vector space over a field $K$. Then $G$ acts on the vector space $V$, but we additionally insist that $G$ respects the vector space operations, i.e. the action is via $K$-linear transformations. The study of (linear) representations brings in tools from linear algebra to the study of the properties of a group.

There are other kinds of interesting group actions. If we want to study the action of a group $G$ on a topological space/a manifold/an algebraic variety $X$, then we naturally want the action to consist of bijections observing the extra structure, i.e. continuous/differentiable/rational respectively.

The various kinds of representations of $G$ are related. Of course, all the representations are permutations of the elements of $X$, but that is not necessarily very interesting (e.g. nearby points are often permuted by the exact same permutations not shedding additional light to the group $G$). However, nearly all the actions listed above give rise to interesting linear representations. The permutations can be turned into monomial matrices by interpreting the elements of $X$ as (formal) basis vectors, the actions on a topological space/manifold/variety lead to linear actions on the (co)homology spaces.

Also, the study of group representations is always a 2-way street. We use properties of $X$ to study $G$, and conversely we use properties of $G$ to study $X$. For example, the result known as (not) Burnside's lemma is a nice tool in combinatorics. And in the 60s-70s the physicists used properties of groups of symmetries of nature to deduce/predict what kind of elementary particles must exist.

Comment: Answering to participate in the Crusade only, hence CW.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of an equivalence between representations and linear actions, I have found that the one induces the other (and conversely, too). The following mappings hopefully clarify the idea.

Suppose $\rho \colon G \to \mathrm{GL}(V)$ is a representation. Define $\phi \colon G \times V \to V$ by the map $(g, v) \mapsto \rho(g)v$ and prove it is a linear action. Note that since $\rho$ is a representation, by definition $\rho(g) \in \mathrm{GL}(V)$ for all $g \in G$. Using this linearity you can prove that $\phi$ is a linear action.

Conversely, suppose $\phi \colon G\times V \to V$ is a linear action and define $\rho \colon G \to \mathrm{GL}(V)$ by the map $g \mapsto \phi(g, \cdot)$, where $\cdot$ a placeholder for an element of $V$. To show that $\rho(g)$ is linear for all $g \in G$, use the fact that $\phi$ is a linear action: 
\begin{equation}
\rho(g)(\lambda v + w) = \phi(g, \lambda v + w) = \lambda \phi(g,v) + \phi(g, w) = \lambda \rho(g)v + \rho(g)w.
\end{equation}
Conclude that $\rho(g)$ is indeed linear. So a representation induces a linear action, and a linear action induces a representation.

Comment: While this is correct, it does not address the actual problem the OP had, which was that the word "linear" was missing from the action needed to make a (linear) representation.

Comment: Agreed, though I noticed the OP has chosen the standard representation (instead of an arbitrary one) to show equivalence. Since the 'linear issue' was solved in the comments, I tried to address the problem of showing that representations are linear actions and vice versa the general way.